# How to access data in a string via KQL

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

KQL beginner here - I have some CEF logs hitting one of my servers and I need to get into the data to get some meaningful reports from it.

Take this log - not json, just a string

```
CEF:0|vendor1|vendorproduct|1.0|Event1|Event2|1|source_ip=0.0.0.0 rt=2020-04-28T04:17:05.475Z data1=example1 group=example2 endpoint=55555555 user=444444
```

I want to access each field and store as a var for further query use. What is the best way to achieve this so I can have results such as the below? Regex? String functions?

```
 | extend vendorname =    // = vendor1
 | extend source_ip =     // = 0.0.0.0
 | extend endpoint =      // = 55555555
// etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I figured this one out - see below for KQL to achieve what I was looking for:

```
Syslog 
 | where SyslogMessage has "vendor-name"
 | extend logs = split(SyslogMessage, "|") 
 | extend vendor = logs[1]
 | extend app = logs[2]
 | extend version = logs[3]
 | extend event = logs[4]
 | extend msg = logs[5]
 | parse SyslogMessage with * "source_ip=" source_ip "rt=" rt " id=" id " data1=" data1 " group=" group " endpoint=" endpoint "user=" user 
 | project vendor, app, version, event, msg, rt, data1, source_ip, id, group, endpoint, user
```